# Algorithm for line-breaking text (Wrap text to fit 'page')

Tags: algorithm, text, graphics

I've developed a few GUI-oriented applications that implement their own text line-breaking algorithms. For example, consider that my applications consist of typical GUI "widgets" that can be laid out on a screen. Widgets such as checkboxes, textfields, simple labels, etc, are fairly easy to draw. However, a widget such as a "paragraph" (an arbitrary amount of multiline text, which should be fit into a specified box, with line-breaking occurring as necessary) is much more difficult owing to the, well, line-breaking part.

Every time I've implemented such an algorithm, I've used an approach that's worked but has been pretty inefficient. My general approach (to fit a string into a box with width ***w***) has been to iteratively take a string ***s***, use font metrics to measure its pixel length ***l***, and whittle away at it until l <= w. Then the remainder is assigned to ***s***, and I repeat the process until I'm left with a value of ***s*** that's less than or equal to ***w***.

At the bottom of this is a Javascript example (which admittedly probably isn't the best environment in which to be doing this sort of thing). This code would be part of the aforementioned "paragraph" widget, and is written for the HTML5 Canvas API (*ctx* is the Canvas' graphics context). Clearly, the Big-O analysis of this approach is pretty poor. But... is there a better way to do this sort of thing? I'm assuming it depends somewhat on the environment in which we're working. But I also assume that given the number of text-editing tools that exist, an efficient solution exists out there.

```
    // the paragraph widgets' main drawing function
    this.drawText = function(ctx) {
        ... 

        var lines = this.text.split("\n"); // here we account for user-entered line breaks
        var y = this.y;

        for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
            var currTxt = lines[i]; // a chunk of text in between user-entered line breaks
            var miniLines = this.breakToLines(currTxt, this.textWidth(), ctx);
            for (var j = 0; j < miniLines.length; j++) {
                var miniTxt = miniLines[j];

                var x = this.x + ( (this.round) ? this.cornerRadius : 0 );

                x += this.textOffset();
                y += this.fontSize;

                ctx.save();
                ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                ctx.clip();

                ctx.fillText(miniTxt, x, y);
                ctx.restore();
            }

        };
    };

    // take a chunk of text and break it into lines that fit within width 'w'
    this.breakToLines = function(txt, w, ctx) {
        var arr = [];
        while (true) {
            var txt2 = this.popLine(txt, w, ctx);
            if (txt2 == null)
                break;
            arr.push(txt2);
            if (txt.length <= txt2.length)
                break;
            txt = txt.substring(txt2.length);
        }
        return arr;
    };

    this.popLine = function(txt, w, ctx) {
        var m = ctx.measureText(txt); // 'm' represents the size of the text
        if (m.length == 0)
            return null;  // 'm' is empty, so we're done
        while (m.width > w) {
            // remove a word from txt and re-measure it
            txt = txt.substring(0, txt.lastIndexOf(' '));
            m = ctx.measureText(txt);
        }
        return txt;
    };
```

Comment: you should measure what takes too long so you know where the bottleneck is. I do not see anything obvious (but I do not code in this environment). From optimization side avoid heap trashing (you got a lot of it) for example you pass txt as function operand try to pass it in some 'locally' global variable instead so it is not allocated/copied/dealocated over and over again. Also check your string manipulation if it isn't reallocated during substring (maybe cut operation will be faster). If font metric is the problem and you use just ASCII (not UTF) then make and use char width table instead.

Comment: also you can try to estimate wrapped text length by some average char length and start cutting from it plus some safety length to avoid cutting long lines too much times ... or measure whole line length and use similarity to estimate the correct line length in the same way...

Comment: @Spektre, good observation on the heap thrashing, and other Javascript API-related suggestions. The char width table is an interesting idea, but unfortunately the character set is arbitrary user-entered data (and is not limited to ASCII); the font attributes would also be arbitrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if the text metrics give reliable results when measuring the size of a word followed by a space. For example, does `width( "aaa " ) + width( "bbb" ) = width( "aaa bbb" )`? If so you can measure each word in the text, with and without a space after it, and figure the rest out from there.  Plan B (assuming that text metrics for a word followed by a space doesn't give precise results) is to measure each word without the space, and use a fixed value to estimate the space between words.

The inefficiency in the current algorithm, as I see it, is that you're calling the `measureText` method O(*n^2*) times, and you're measuring the width of long strings. By breaking the text into words and measuring each word, you would only call `measureText` O(*n*) times, and you would be calling it on relatively short strings.

The proposed algorithm then is to start at the beginning of each line and add words until the wrap limit is reached.  This *additive* approach to the problem reduces the number of strings that must be measured, as well as reducing the length of the strings that must measured.

Comment: +1 for bringing up the key concept of *additivity*.  But if the width is additive (as it really ought to be, I think), then you can use a much simpler approach: just repeatedly nibble off characters from the *start* until you find you exceed w.

Comment: Good point and thanks for the +1 :)  I was working off the assumption that proportional fonts are almost never *additive* due to kerning and ligatures.  That is, one can't assume that the widths of the characters making up a word will be additive. The best one can hope for is that the space character between words is of constant width, or only depends on the final character of the preceding word.

Comment: I had forgotten about kerning and ligatures -- so yes, it makes sense to measure a word at a time.  Though I think it's still a good idea to emphasise in your answer that the key point is to proceed forwards from the start, rather than backwards from the end.

Comment: @user3386109, you're right; building up each line would definitely be the more efficient approach than the subtractive approach I'd developed. I think there are a few different variations on that approach to choose from.